# Update value in php array

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, everytime I add a number for a unique name - it is being added to another page. At some point, I want to check the array and update that number for the unique name if it already exists.

For example,

```
Benj 25
Mark 68 
Sam 34
```

If I add a new value under Benj say 50 - I now want the total to be 75

I understand it is something to do with checking the `array_key_exists` function but it keeps printing the word array and I don't even know how to get just that number and update it

This is my code:

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$number = isset($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : "";

if(!isset($_SESSION['numbers'])){
    $_SESSION['numbers'] = array();
}


if(array_key_exists($name, $_SESSION['numbers'])){
    print_r(array_keys($_SESSION['numbers'][$name]));
}
else{
    $_SESSION['numbers'][$name] = array("name"=>$name, "number"=>$number);
}
?>
```

EDIT: After doing `var_dump($_SESSION["numbers"]);` I get this:

```
array(2) { [3]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "3" ["number"]=> string(2) "55" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(1) "2" ["number"]=> string(2) "54" } }
```

I think I am going about it the right way I just dont know how to retrieve and update the number

Any help will mean a lot

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($_SESSION["numbers"]);`?

Comment: i mean where do I type var_dump($_SESSION["numbers"]);

Comment: Just right before you use it, so we see what exact array structure you have.

Comment: And if I understand your question right you get a name and a number in via GET and now if it doesn't exist in your `$_SESSION["numbers"]` array you want to add it, like this: `["name" => $name, "number" => $number]`. And if the name already exist in the array you want to add that number to it?

Comment: yes that is correct. if the name already exists, just add the new value to the existing one. BTW, I have edited the question to show you my array structure

Comment: `print_r(array_keys($_SESSION['numbers'][$name]));` should be replaced by your code to update the number.  But something looks off about your array structure.

Comment: Just do it like this: `if(isset($_SESSION["numbers"][$name])){
    $_SESSION["numbers"][$name]["number"] += $number;
} else {
    $_SESSION["numbers"][$name] = array("name" => $name, "number" => $number);
}`

Comment: This is similar to the answer below and it doesn't work on first attempt i.e when you assign a number to a name for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```html
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$number = isset($_GET['number']) ? $_GET['number'] : "";

if(!isset($_SESSION['numbers'])){
    $_SESSION['numbers'] = array();
}


if(array_key_exists($name, $_SESSION['numbers'])){
    $_SESSION['numbers'][$name]['number'] += $number;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['numbers'][$name] = array("name"=>$name, "number"=>$number);
}
```

Comment: this works, however when I add a new number for a new name for the FIRST time nothing is being added. When I add it the second time, then it is being added for the first time and after that it works :). BUT it doesn't work as in add any value at the start.

Comment: so when you add a number for a name for the first time - the number is always zero and not the input value. when you type it again then only after it works

Comment: Well, that's weird. In the code above is no reason for this behaviour. Where you are doing the `var_dump` and is there any code below the snippet you posted? Or try to `var_dump($number)` and `var_dump($_SESSION['numbers'][$name])` just after you created that. it seems like there is something wrong with the `$number` variable itself.

Comment: im doing the `var_dump` at the top. I also have `session_start();` at the top

Comment: not sure if that `(session_start();)` is what is causing

Comment: It is printing the value for `var_dump($number)` BUT for `var_dump($_SESSION['numbers'][$name])` it is printing `NULL`

Comment: `NULL` even you dumped it after this line: `$_SESSION['numbers'][$name] = array("name"=>$name, "number"=>$number);` ? And just a hint: the `session_start()` should be the very first line in this case.

Comment: Hi mate. Sorry for the late response I feel asleep last night. Turns out, I may have been completely OUT of it last night (lack of sleep) and I was dumping and inserting the number into the wrong variable, WHOOPS :p.

Comment: Anyways, I have upvoted and accepted your answer as you responded prompt. Thanks +1. IT ALL WORKS NOW!!! CHEERS

Comment: I am glad it helped. The lack of sleep is always tricky in term of seeing things from the right view :)